# Django search multiple filters

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Lets say I have a model

**models.py**

```
class user:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class job:
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class user_job:
    user = models.ForeignKey('user')
    job  = models.ForeignKey('job')
```

**forms.py**

```
 jobs = (
     ('0', 'a'),
     ('1', 'b'),
     ('2', 'c'),
 )

 class searchForm:
     box = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                          choices = jobs,
                                          widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                          label   = 'Search',
                                         )
```

I can search for users that have job 'a' with

```
user_job.objects.filter(job__exact = 'a') ...
```

I tried to search for users that have both job 'a' and job 'c' like so

```
search_q = user_job.objects.filter(job__exact = 'a')
search_q = search_q.filter(job__exact = 'c')
```

but I get all users that have job 'a' *or* job 'c', and I need all users that have *both* jobs.

Is there a way I can filter it through Django, or do I need to filter on one job and then iterate through the results and check for the 2nd job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll probably find it easier to search from the `User` model since what you want is a list of `Users`s who have both jobs. Django automatically sets up properties on your models that allow you to access related models both from model instances and in DB queries.

Assuming you set up your models like so:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: %s>' % self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Job: %s>' % self.name

class UserJob(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<UserJob: %s %s>' % (self.user.name, self.job.name)
```

And populate it as follows:

```
u1 = User.objects.create(name='u1')
u2 = User.objects.create(name='u2')
u3 = User.objects.create(name='u3')

a = Job.objects.create(name='a')
b = Job.objects.create(name='b')
c = Job.objects.create(name='c')

UserJob.objects.create(user=u1, job=a)
UserJob.objects.create(user=u2, job=a)
UserJob.objects.create(user=u2, job=b)
UserJob.objects.create(user=u3, job=a)
UserJob.objects.create(user=u3, job=c)
```

The following query will return you user 3, which is the only user who has both "Job a" and "Job c":

```
u = User.objects.filter(userjob__job=a).filter(userjob__job=c)
```

(or, if you prefer to refer to the jobs by name rather than Job instance):

```
u = User.objects.filter(userjob__job__name='a').filter(userjob__job__name='c')
```

You can see how Django is allowing you to traverse the related fields from the `User` model to the `UserJob` model with the double underscore notation (the Django docs on this are here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships.

Once you get the `User` object back, you can similarly access the UserJob instances using the relationship properties that Django adds to the model:

```
u = User.objects.filter(userjob__job__name='a').filter(userjob__job__name='c')
jobs = u.userjob_set.all()
```

Comment: hmm, this works, I dont quite get it how but it just works :D ... why do I look in User.objects.filter ? and not in UserJob.objects.filter ? if you can ... can you give me a little sql of how this will look like ... anyway thx a lot this is just what I needed ... thx for your time and GL

Comment: You're filtering off the `User` object because what you want back is a list of Users (this based on the fact that the problem-domain question is "Which users have both job a and job c?"). It's also semantically easier to formulate a sane django query for that problem by starting with the `User` object.

You can see the SQL statements that django generates by inspecting the results of `django.db.connection`: `from django.db import connection; print connection.queries`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-filter
```

Then add django-filter in your install apps:

```
'django_filters'
```

Then create a new file like `filter.py`

```
import django_filters
from rent.models import Rent
from django.views import View

class RentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Rent
        fields = [
            'name', 'bed_room', 'bath_room', 'rent_location', 'types'
        ]
```

After that import `RentFilter` in your `views.py` then follow the step:

```
class BookingFilerListView(View):

def get(self, request):
    booking_list = Booking.objects.all()
    booking_filer = BookingFilter(request.GET, queryset=booking_list)
    template = 'booking/booking_filter.html'
    ctx = {'result': booking_filer}
    return render(request, template, ctx)
```

Finally, in your `booking_filter.html` template look like this:

```
              <form method="get">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone_number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="transaction_id">Transaction ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Transaction ID" name="transaction_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="booking_date">Booking Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Booking Date" name="booking_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status">Booking Date</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
                            <option value="0">PENDING</option>
                            <option value="1">CANCEL</option>
                            <option value="2">PROGRESS</option>
                            <option value="3">DONE</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Filter Booking</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Print the output in your template bottom:

```
                      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                            <th>Transaction ID</th>
                            <th>Booking Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% if result %}
                            {% for obj in result.qs %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ obj.phone_number }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ obj.transaction_id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ obj.booking_date }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                        {% endif %}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```